# Cannot install asdf erlang on MAC OSX Mojave

Tags: erlang, asdf-vm

I am trying to install Erlang in a Mac OS system with Mojave on it. However the installation hangs for no apparent reason:

```
$ asdf install erlang 22.2.8
asdf_22.2.8 is not a kerl-managed Erlang/OTP installation
The asdf_22.2.8 build has been deleted
Extracting source code
Building Erlang/OTP 22.2.8 (asdf_22.2.8), please wait...
```

I know the issue is not the network, as I have downloaded everything and the step that hangs forever is the Building step.

I have removed and re-installed both asdf and Erlang from scratch as well, but it didn't fix the issue.

I believe I have all necessary dependencies as well, otherwise the re-installation would have failed.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: *the step that hangs forever is the Building step.* -- How long is forever?  7 minutes, 1 hour, 14 hours, 27 days?

Comment: Over 4 hours, on a Macbook Pro with 16GB RAM and an intel i7 core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `~/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_22.2.8` and look at the `otp_build_22.2.8.log` file. It should tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

Thanks to the post by @legoscia I went to `~/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_22.2.8` and looked at the `otp_build_22.2.8.log` while it was still being built.

By checking this I was actually able to find out that I had a problem with my brew installation, which in turn meant I was using a very outdated version of XCode and XTools.

By forcing an upgrade on my machine (and as a consequence fixing my broken brew installation), I was then able to smoothly run and install `asdf install erlang`.

I know this is the solution, but I will give credit to @legoscia, as without him/her I would not have been able to fix my issue.